# Коллекция значений свойства JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Напиши функцию `getProductPrice(productName)` которая принимает один параметр `productName` - название продукта. Функция ищет объект продукта с таким именем (свойство name) в массиве `products` и возвращает его цену (свойство `price`). Если продукт с таким названием не найден, функция должна возвращать `null`.

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'Radar', price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'Scanner', price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'Droid', price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: 'Grip', price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

function getProductPrice(productName) {
  // Change code below this line
  for (const key of products) {
    if (key.name === productName) {
      return key.price;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getProductPrice('Scanner'));
```

Не работает функция,  в чём может быть ошибка?
Нужно решить именно через перебор `for..of`

Comment: Функцию предполагается не только объявить, но и вызвать. Вызова `getProductPrice` в коде нет, вот она и не работает (отдыхает).

Comment: функция вызывается сама, это тест с автопроверкой. То есть если написана функция правильно после нажатия проверить она сама вызывается и проверяется ( забыл уточнить)

Comment: блок `else` не нужен

Comment: _«забыл уточнить»_ - исправил. Последующие вопросы исправляй самостоятельно, пожалуйста (т.к. работоспособность примера сказывается и на ответах, и на репутации иногда).

Comment: хорошо , спасибо

Comment: При переборе объектов в массиве, _на первой же итерации цикла_ выполняется либо возврат из функции значения цены (если элемент массива соответствует условию), либо возврат из функции значения `null`. То есть, выполнение функции "на первом элементе" завершается в любом случае, и это неправильно. Эта ошибка алгоритмическая, и как Grundy верно заметил, блок "иначе" тут не нужен - если его убрать (написав `return null;` после цикла), то будут перебираться все элементы массива до подходящего к условию возврата из функции (или пока элементы не закончатся), как и положено по условиям задачи.

Comment: понял, дальше буду знать,  спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const products = [
  { name: 'Radar', price: 1300, quantity: 4 },
  { name: 'Scanner', price: 2700, quantity: 3 },
  { name: 'Droid', price: 400, quantity: 7 },
  { name: 'Grip', price: 1200, quantity: 9 },
];

function getProductPrice(productName) {
  for (const item of products)
    if (item.name === productName)
      return item.price;
  return null;
}

console.log(getProductPrice("Droid"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! 
Можно узнать почему мой вариант не работал полностью как надо?  Из-за блока else? или скобки какие-то?  пытаюсь понять правильно ли я мыслил когда писал свой вариант

Comment: @AliBurzhi Потому что у Вас `return null;` был внутри цикла. Если передать имя не первого элемента массива, то функция завершается на первой итерации, возвращая `null`.

Comment: Благодарю, теперь понял как правильно!

Comment: @Ali Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.